# Не могу задать border

Tags: html, css

Проблема такова. Задаю `border`, но он не задаётся.

```
.example{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-left: 500px;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background: red;
        border-top-width: 20px;
        border-left-width: 20px;
        border-right-width: 20px;
        border-bottom-width: 20px;
  }
```

Пробовал и через

```
.example{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-left: 500px;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background: red;
        border:20px
}
```

Но если нажимаю в инспекторе на края, но моё значение предлагает, могу помять на 1 единицу и бордер появится. Что я делаю не так? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забыли указать стиль линии. Попробуйте так:

```
.example{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-left: 500px;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background: red;
        border: 20px solid #000;
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое